# Unauthorized error when using Spring Security and Angular

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My frontend is based on Angular 4 and my backend is based on Spring Boot with Spring Security.
I am deploying everything in a single WAR file.

I created a **static/landing** folder in **/src/main/resources** and then I put the Webpack-built Angular files in that folder.

Angular is taking care of the login process and so I created the following rule in Spring Security :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter mappingIndex() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("forward:/landing/index.html");
        }
    };
   }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(),ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .antMatchers(/"login/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Unfortunately, I am always getting the HTTP Status code 401 (Unauthorized) when trying to access the /login page with the webbrowser for signing in.

How can I achieve to integrate the Angular App in this way ? Because my Security rules are working fine with the REST Apis.

Answer (score 0):

`.antMatchers(/"login/**").permitAll()` looks wrong,

try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

if it still doesn't work, add to your application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace
```

and post output